# Number of Views?

Tags: support, site-promotion

How did [Why might it be advisable to keep student debt vs. paying it off quickly?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/29120/why-might-it-be-advisable-to-keep-student-debt-vs-paying-it-off-quickly) get nearly 2K views so quickly? The questions before and after are at a tiny fraction of this number.

Is this a case of it being featured on some external site?

Comment: I see nothing specific, but perhaps the analytics will show up tomorrow.  It just takes a link from one popular site.  I hope we end up with some more fans and community.

Comment: And not just views, its got lots of answers around 11 so far and quite a few answers from first time users who posted an answer ... We need more of these questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Sometimes, new questions get *featured* in the ["hot network questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions) sidebar. This sidebar also appears at **other** sites in the Stack Exchange network, including high volume ones like Stack Overflow.

So, based on the views, I would guess that question was featured. This sometimes also explains why these posts see answers from users new to *Money*, but established already at other sites (reputation starting at 101 is indicative of a user with 200+ reputation at another SE.)

Traffic from other sources is possible, too. One of the [diy.stackexchange.com](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) questions I had asked about [nails vs. screws](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/918/is-there-a-case-where-nails-are-better-than-screws-from-an-engineering-structur) was [mentioned on Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5990779/screws-vs-nails-when-do-you-use-one-or-the-other) some time ago.

**Also**, *Money* was just featured in the [Stack Exchange podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/03/podcast-56-green-or-red-curae/). We are the "community of the week", apparently!

Comment: Thanks. It just struck me how fast that question visit count skyrocketed.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Indeed! There was another like that, too, that similarly surprised me: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/27919/im-saving-money-too-fast-what-should-i-do